# Jump from word to word in Guake with Ctrl + Left/Right

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts, guake

I am using the drop-down terminal emulator [guake](http://guake.org/) and would like to jump from word/command to word/command by pressing Ctrl + Left and Ctrl + Right, respectively, as it is possible in programs like gnome terminal and LibreOffice.

How can I achieve this?